# MySQL delayed foreign key check. Is it possible?

Tags: mysql, foreign-keys

Is it possible make constraints check on transaction level?
For example, there is structure:

`CREATE TABLE _users (
  id INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  value VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (id)
) ENGINE = InnoDB;`

`CREATE TABLE _visits (
  id INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  user_id INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  FOREIGN KEY (user_id) REFERENCES _users (id)
) ENGINE = InnoDB;`

Here is example of query, where i want to trigger fk check.
Is it possible? If not, are there any other methods to make delayed check.

```
START TRANSACTION;
SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS = 0;
INSERT INTO _visits (id, user_id) VALUES (1,1);
INSERT INTO _users (id, value) VALUES (1, 'value');
SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS = 1;
-- HERE I WANT TO TRIGGER CONSTRAINT CHECKS
COMMIT;
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [In MySQL, can I defer referential integrity checks until commit](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5014700/in-mysql-can-i-defer-referential-integrity-checks-until-commit)