# SQL insert statement two tables with crossed foreign keys

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two tables `ACCOUNTS` and `ACCOUNT_LIMITS` and they have crossed foreign keys.

```
ACCOUNTS
--------
id (PK)
account_limits_id (FK)
username

ACCOUNT_LIMITS
--------------
id (PK)
account_id (FK)
limit
```

I shortened the real example. My question is, How can I make an insert statement for both tables?

Comment: Why do you want to have FK on both sides?

Comment: @PeterHenell thank you for your answer. I did not define the table, but I think it is for guarantee the one to one relationship.

Comment: If you can change it it is better to have a unique constraint on the account_id in the account_limits table instead of having the accounts_limits_id in the accounts table.

Comment: If you cannot change it then you need to disable the FK constraint while inserting and then re-enable it after insert. It seems MySql cannot deal with deferred integrity checks (based on this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5014700/in-mysql-can-i-defer-referential-integrity-checks-until-commit)

Comment: @PeterHenell my bad, on the table `accounts` the `account_limits_id` can be null. However it is also defined as a foreign key. Thank you for your answers although, they were helpful.