# Easily alter table data to add foreign keys without restraints

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to add foreign keys to a testing database seeded with a bunch of dummy data. I could go outside MySQL, export a list of missing IDs, and generate a bunch of insert statements in Python but I'm wondering if there is a way to handle this in MySQL

```
ALTER TABLE `kalos`.`award` 
CHANGE COLUMN `awardee_user_id` `awardee_user_id` INT(11) NULL ;
ALTER TABLE `kalos`.`award` 
ADD CONSTRAINT `fk_award_3`
  FOREIGN KEY (`awardee_user_id`)
  REFERENCES `kalos`.`user` (`user_id`)
  ON DELETE RESTRICT
  ON UPDATE CASCADE;
```

I've tried messing with the `ON DELETE` and `ON UPDATE` properties but it definitely won't let me apply it because there are user ID's in the `award` table that are not present in the `user` table (only about 200 out of 3000). Like I said it would be fairly simple to do this in Python but I've run into this issue a few times and am really curious to see if MySQL can handle something like this on it's own.

Comment: Somewhat related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/5014700/2422776

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured this out and it was extremely simple.

```
DELETE FROM t1 
WHERE
    t1.id NOT IN (SELECT 
        id
    FROM
        (SELECT 
            tmp.id AS id
        FROM
            t1
        INNER JOIN t2 ON t1.id = t2.id) as tmp)
```

This will delete any row from t1 that does not have a corresponding record in t2