# Mimicing Deferred Constraint with MySQL in Hibernate

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, spring-data-jpa

As I understand from the [MySQL documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-table-foreign-keys.html) and from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5014700/in-mysql-can-i-defer-referential-integrity-checks-until-commit), it is NOT POSSIBLE to use deferred constraint in MySQL.

So, my question is; with below entity model (a uni-directional relation) in Hibernate, I want to swap two a collection of `Package` between two `Product` entities within a `Transaction`.

```
 public class Product{
 @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinTable(
            name="product_selected_packages",
            joinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "product")},
            inverseJoinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name="packages",unique = true)},
            uniqueConstraints = {@UniqueConstraint(name = "UK_package",columnNames = {"packages"})}
    )
    private List<Package> packages;

}


public class Package {

    @Column(unique = true)
    private String code;
}
```

But when I write this type of code below (this is all done within a `@Transactional` method),

```
List<Package> product1Packages = new ArrayList<>(product1.getPackages()); // save product1 packages into memory

product1.getPackages().clear(); // clear all product1 packages
session.flush(); // flush session in order to sync db with hibernate 

product2.getPackages().addAll(product1Packages);
```

Of course there is a more complex logic behind it but in a general way, Hibernate produces below SQL(which makes sense)

```
START TRANSACTION;

DELETE FROM product_selected_packages WHERE product = :SOME_ID; 

INSERT INTO product_selected_packages(product,packages) VALUES (1,1) , (1,2) , (1,3) ...;

ROLLBACK; -- OR COMMIT
```

But due to MySQL's limitations on constraints which is stated in the documentation; above statement throws an error.

```
Duplicate entry '1621' for key 'UK_unique_index_constraint'
```

Because documentation states;

> MySQL checks foreign key constraints immediately; the check is not
>   deferred to transaction commit.

Long story short, how can I create a work-around method for this type of situation **without losing the `Transaction` ?**

Comment: Why exactly does it throw an error? All relevant foreign keys should be fine, shouldn't they? Or do you have something else referring to `produtct_selected_packages`?

Comment: I've added the exception in the question

Comment: So where is this `UK_unique_index_constraint` come from? And on which table and columns is it?

Comment: Because it's a uni-directional relationship, this Unique Constraint lies on the "product_selected_packages" table which is created by the hibernate automatically (combining two tables). Has two columns, product (FK to Product) and packages (FK to Package).

Comment: I don't think so. It says "Duplicate entry '1621'. This seems to indicate that the constraint has only one column.

Comment: I'm sorry, you're right. Contraint only works for one column which is "packages" field. But that's the correct behaviour, that's what we want. What is wrong is that , row that points to '1621'  package with some product should be removed from db before inserting into another product.

Comment: So Hibernate is not issuing the statements given in the question? What statements is it issuing?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/216048/discussion-between-jens-schauder-and-paroxit).